# std::variant duplicate type cause no suitable constructor error(clang-1300.0.29.3)

Tags: c++, c++17

Just wondering if this is the expected behaviour of `std::variant`, as well as the reasoning for this behaviour.

Simplified code to reproduce the error is as below:

```
double d= 1.0;
std::variant<std::monostate, double, double> v(d);
```

The error message is shown as below:

```
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "double" to "std::__1::variant<std::__1::monostate, std::__1::remove_cv_t<std::__1::remove_reference_t<double &>>, std::__1::remove_cv_t<std::__1::remove_reference_t<double &>>>"C/C++(415)
```

One solution I found now is to create a metafunction that removes duplicates from the variant type and then construct with the variable of the type `double`.

i.e.

```
distinct<std::variant<std::monostate, double, double>>v(d);
//distinct_t<std::variant<std::monostate, double, double>> -> std::variant<std::monostate, double>
```

If there is any better solution, please also let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having multiple identical types in a `std::variant` is allowed. However, when the constructor of `std::variant` is invoked, overload resolution is performed to figure out which of the variant types it needs to hold. If you have 2 identical types, there's an ambiguity, and so you get an error.

You can specify which of the types you want to use explicitly

```
std::variant<std::monostate, double, double> v(std::in_place_index<1>, d);
```

which will use the first `double` of the `std::variant`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding the reasoning, I have the following questions. If there are two doubles(any duplicated identical types), what is the point to treat them differently(i.e. first double and second double)?  In what case you may want to use the second double?

Comment: @X.J.L It allows you to have a variant of 2 doubles with different meanings, without needing them to be different types.

Comment: Thanks again. I mean I understand the concept from your explanation, but I just didn't get why this is something useful and in what case this might be useful. Could you provide some concrete example to help me understand it?

Comment: @X.J.L Here's a generic example from the top of my head. Say your function returns number of successfully processed items - an int, or an error code - also an int.
Or a type that represents ip address v4 or v6. The underlying type for both of them can be one type. Just like in [enum in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html).

Comment: @AndrewSmeltzov Thank you for providing a concrete example.  that helps a lot!

Comment: How does `operator=` work in this case?  Create another variant and assign it?